Effect of low pass filter in ADC when the pin direction is changed from input to output
Consider a circuit to measure ADC :

The ADC pin is changed from input to output every 5 seconds and the pin is read for analog value.
Every 5 seconds it is made high for 100 ms, low for 100ms and then back to input mode.
I observe that the value discharges slightly from the capacitors when it is changed to output mode. I think the voltage discharges from 5V to the previous input value in sometime.
Can someone explain me what is happening here? How do I predict the time it requiries to discharge to previous ADC value?

The settling time of this system will be dominated by R2 and C2, since R2 is so much greater than R1. As a guide, the time it takes for an RC filter to settle to within 1% of "final" voltage is about 5RC, which in your case is:
$$ 5 \times 100k\Omega \times 1\mu F = 0.5s $$
To arrive within 0.1%, expect to have to wait:
$$ 7 \times 100k\Omega \times 1\mu F = 0.7s $$
Connecting a large capacitor C2 to ground, directly from a GPIO output, is an abuse of that output. It will cause the output to pass far more current than it is rated to tolerate, for a short while following each output transition. That might be OK, depending on the MCU, but you should Limit current using another resistor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R3 will protect the MCU's IO when it is an output, but is small compared to R2+R1 and the ADC's input resistance, so it shouldn't influence the potential seen by the ADC when the pin is an input, and will have little effect on settling time.
